# Install DRBD binary package for CentOS in RHEL v5 64 bit

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rhel, drbd

i want to ask , i have installing DRBD binary package for CentOS on RHEL v5, there is 2 files.


1. drbd83-8.3.13-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm 
2. kmod-drbd83-8.3.13-1.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm

first i execute **drbd83-8.3.13-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm** file with `rpm -i <filename>`, and then i execute **kmod-drbd83-8.3.13-1.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm** file with same command, but the second operation give output below :

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        kernel(rhel5_lib_u6) = aab649531cab69cbeff5665f2aef9e0dba844b20 is needed by kmod-drbd83-8.3.13-1.el5.centos.x86_64
```

so what i must to do ??
i know, it required dependencies file named is **aab649531cab69cbeff5665f2aef9e0dba844b20**, but i do know what is **aab649531cab69cbeff5665f2aef9e0dba844b20** ??

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the kernel DRBD module (driver) you install is not built for the kernel version you have. The kernel version can be seen using

```
rpm -qa | grep kernel
```

Ensure that you have updated your Centos system (using 'yum update') and that you have the last relevant kmod-drbd.

On the Centos packages repository I can see that there is [a newer drbd-kmod version than yours](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/extras/x86_64/RPMS/)